# how to connect several mutually independent computers to one computer?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems

I don't know what the mechanism is called and how to create one. The basic idea is that the computers A, B, C, D, E are mutually exclusive. The systems A, B... and so on have only a monitor, mouse and keyboard. They do not have their own CPUs (or do they?)

[image: The diagram of the system that I want]

My previous college had such systems in the library. There were several monitor-mouse-keyboard sets that were always on and we just needed to input a username and password to access that particular set. Different sets had different ID and passwords for gaining access. Lets say I would create a PDF report in system A then that information can be accessed from system A whenever I logged in next time.

My questions are-:

1. Did the college have CPUs for each system hidden in a another room so that students can't mess with them?
2. Can this type of system be created using some specific software or hardware or OS?

It would be great if anyone could direct me to keywords that can help me to research this topic on my own. I can't even get started!

P.S. If my question is not clear then please ask me any specific things that I can give you information about.

Comment: They most likely had thin clients and some remote desktop solution. Otherwise you would get this with a really classic mainframe setup which is highly unusual today. Depending on the work you need to do they could also be fat clients just using some web application and running in a kind of Kiosk mode.

Comment: @Seth Thanks for introducing the term thin client and Kiosk mode. I have no idea what they are but I'll use these terms to identify that process. Thanks! :D

Comment: The subject line alone sounds like a regular computer network, or client-server arrangement. Also reminds me of [computer clusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the system you are describing had a computer with a number of "[thin clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client)" attached to it.

Thin clients technically have a (simple) CPU, but are used to send information to and from a primary computer to do most of the heavy processing and calculation.  The primary computer would also handle logons and permissions.

There are thin client setups for many/most OS's, including both Windows and Linux.

You have not described the setup very well, but it could also use a simpler, but similar concept of dumb terminals or smart terminals [ these have less CPU's and functionality then thin clients.

Comment: I'll look into the keywords- thin client, dumb and smart terminals. Thanks for giving me a point to start :)